# How to persist an object in Haskell to a memory location via unsafePerformIO or similar

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, persistence, in-memory

In a Haskell system I don't have much control over, I provide a syntactically pure function with the following signature:

```
doTheWork :: Int -> TheInput -> MyResult
doTheWork counter data = ...
```

This function does some work and returns its result. However the function is called again and again (until the system resource are used up) with incremented `Int`s to do more work on the same problem (the *same* `TheInput` data).

So to make use of the fact to be called again and again and not every time start again, I would need to store the intermediate `MyResults`. Of course, the "proper" semantically pure way would be that the system calls the function together with the old last results; i.e. the function signature would be something like `doTheWork :: MyResult -> Int -> TheInput -> MyResult`, but I have no control over the signature. The signature my function has to conform to is the shown at the beginning of the question! And I cannot move the function into the IO Monad of the program (because I don't have control over where the function is called).

So I was thinking to store the `MyResults` myself in memory via `unsafePerformIO` or similar. However I got stuck on the "safe to memory part". I can print the results out to stdout with something like

```
storeMyResults :: MyResults -> MyResults
storeMyResults data =
  unsafePerformIO $ do
    putStrLn show data)
    return  data
```

and then use `storeMyResults data` at the end of `doTheWork` when returning the results to write them out each time the function has computed new results.

But I have no idea how to write the `MyResults` value to memory and then read it out the next time I get called. I think I could write it to a file, but that's unnecessarily slow.

Is there a way to store a value in a memory location?

Comment: You might be after an `IORef` or a `MVar`

Comment: There's a few red flags here. Who designed the part of the system you don't have control over? Can you smack them with a fish? A little more charitably: what were they thinking that led to this design? Generally, I think you need to play the game [one level up](https://blog.plover.com/math/self-esteem.html). While it may be *possible* to do the technical thing you ask to do, I doubt it will be best for you or your project in the long run.

Comment: Note that `f x y = let z = expensiveFun x in use y z` will re-evaluate `expensiveFun` at each call even if `x` is the same. By contrast, `f x = let z = expensiveFun x in \y -> use y z` allows to write things like `map (f x) list` where `expensiveFun` is evaluated only once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typical way to do this is to `unsafePerformIO` yourself a top-level [`IORef`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Data-IORef.html). `IORef`s normally provide "mutable memory location" functionality *within `IO`*, but you can also break one out of `IO`.

```
data MemoRecord = MemoRecord Int TheInput MyResult
cacheCell :: IORef (Maybe MemoRecord)
cacheCell = unsafePerformIO (newIORef Nothing)
```

At this point, you have a mutable, program-global variable, like you would in C.

Proceed to wire this into `doTheWork`. Note to take care to save the inputs as well as the output, so you can check you're doing the right thing. Again, do this in `IO` and then `unsafePerformIO` yourself out.

```
-- really, it's up to you how you want to do this
-- i'll just write something plausible so you know how

doTheWork :: Int -> TheInput -> MyResult
doTheWork i x = unsafePerformIO $ do
    r <- doTheWorkHinted i x <$> (check =<<) <$> readIORef cacheCell
    writeIORef cacheCell (Just (MemoRecord i x r))
    return r
  where
    -- check :: MemoRecord -> Maybe (Int, MyResult)
    check (MemoRecord i x' r)
      | x == x'   = Just (i, r) -- assuming Eq TheInput; otherwise you may have to resort to System.Mem.StableName, which can give false negatives
      | otherwise = Nothing

-- given an int, the input, and maybe a previous result from the same input, find the result
doTheWorkHinted :: Int -> TheInput -> Maybe (Int, MyResult) -> MyResult
doTheWorkHinted = error "implement this"
```

Comment: Note that for this to work correctly in the face of GHC optimizations, it's important to mark `cacheCell` with a `NOINLINE` pragma. It's not 100% critical for this case, as every call site having its own cache wouldn't be the worst thing in the world, but it would lose potential upside.

Comment: @HTNW, I have tried out this approach - and it seems to work. Super thanks! 

Comment: @Carl Thanks for chiming. This pragma seems to be important to get the benefit from the whole back-and-forth. So, I write on a separate line under the `cacheCell` defintion: `{-# NOINLINE cacheCell #-}. Do I understand this correctly? Sorry I'm not (yet) a Haskell whizz.

Comment: @halloleo Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 2):

This is too long for a comment, but a necessary remark.

Your description strongly suggests that you should **not** dabble with any IO shenanigans to store those values. You don't even need to memoise function results (though that also can be done in a pure fashion, e.g. with [MemoTrie](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MemoTrie-0.6.10/docs/Data-MemoTrie.html)).

Instead, you should simply flip the arguments around and then exploit partial application.

```
doTheWork :: TheInput -> Int -> MyResult
doTheWork inpData
       = \counter -> cheapSpecificComputation counter preciousSharedValue
 where preciousSharedValue = expensiveGeneralComputation inpData
```

This can then be used like

```
map (doTheWork constantInput) [LONG LIST OF COUNTERS]
```

where `preciousSharedValue` will only be computed once and then re-used for all the list. But unlike with a global mutable reference, you don't need to worry about all the things that can go wrong like incorrectly switching context between different `TheInput` values. Laziness, parallelism and more make explicit mutable storage a nightmare.

The flipped order of arguments seems clearly the appropriate one for the way the function is going to be used. You *should* change the signature accordingly. Changing even a large code base to adjust for such a change is pretty easy in Haskell, since the compiler will check exactly where a call to the function needs to be modified.

If this is a library that needs to preserve its interface, then the way to go is to give the flipped version a new name, implement the old-signature one *in terms of it* and deprecate it in favour of the flipped version:

```
workTheDo :: TheInput -> Int -> MyResult
workTheDo inpData = ...

{-# DEPRECATED doTheWork "Use workTheDo" #-}
doTheWork :: Int -> TheInput -> MyResult
doTheWork = flip workTheDo
```

Here, `doTheWork` will work as it did before (and *not* share the `preciousSharedValue` when mapped over a list).

Comment: You might want to note that the last `doTheWork` will still cause `expensiveGeneralComputation` to be evaluated many times. Perhaps, if that interface must absolutely be preserved, one should use some memoization technique on the `TheInput` argument so that we do not repeat the expensive computation.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Sorry, I don't understand this approach. I do not _call_ the  `doTheWork` function, I only _provide_ it. The outer system I have no control over calls the function.

Comment: @halloleo then you should either request that the outer system is changed, or shrug and just add a comment that it's inefficient because the convention doesn't allow persisting the `preciousSharedValue`.

Comment: ...Actually, something based on `MemoTrie` is also still an option.